# Problem on finding integral submanifold of a smooth rank-$2$ distribution .

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-fields, submanifold

$\mathbf {The \ Problem \ is}:$ Let $V_{(x,y,z)}$ be a rank-$2$distribution in $\mathbb R^3$ spanned by $V_1=(x^2+1)(\frac{\partial}{\partial{x}}-\frac{\partial}{\partial{y}})$ & $V_2=\frac{\frac{\partial}{\partial{y}}-\frac{\partial}{\partial{z}}}{x^2+y^2+z^2+1}.$

Show it is a $2$-dimensional smooth distribution & find the integral submanifold of $V$ passing via the origin .

$\mathbf {My \  approach}:$ The smooth part is okay .

For 2nd part, I was trying to find out integral curves of $V_1$ & $V_2$ via $(0,0,0).$

For $V_1$,it's $t \mapsto (\tan t,-\tan t,0)$ but

if $\gamma(t)=(\gamma_1(t),\gamma_2(t),\gamma_3(t))$ be I.C. of $V_2$ via origin then :

$\frac{d\gamma_2}{dt} =\frac{1}{1+(\gamma_2)^2+(\gamma_3)^2}$
&
$\frac{d\gamma_3}{dt} =-\frac{1}{1+(\gamma_2)^2+(\gamma_3)^2}$ .

Is this approach right ?

If yes, then after this I need a moderate hint & I'm a beginner in  differential forms .
Thanks in advance .

Comment: There is an error in $\gamma_3'$: there should be a minus sign. Then, note that $(\gamma_2 + \gamma_3)'=0$. This should be helpful.

Comment: After that, how to find the integral submanifold ? Can u please give a hint ?

Comment: First, show that this integral submanifold exists, e.g by showing that the distribution is involutive and invoking Frobenius Theorem. Show that $[V_1,V_2]=0$, so that their flow commute, and conclude by parametrizing the integral submanifold passing through the origin by composing the flows

Comment: I calculated $[V_1,V_2]$ thrice and found on a local chart $(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ around origin ,the value is $\frac{(x_1^2+1)(x_2-x_1)}{x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2+1}V_2.$ Am I doing anything wrong ?  It would be nice if you post a short answer here .

Comment: To be fair, I didn't do the all calculation thing and you might be right. I thought that was an exercise of classical type, where $[V_1,V_2]=0$. I'm going to think about that particular case and try to answer you more accurately. Sorry about that

Comment: My calculations show that $[V_1,V_2] = -2\frac{(x^2+1)(x-y)}{1+x^2+y^2+y^2} V_2$, which is basically your result up to a factor $2$. Though, this shows that the distribution is involutive, but not solve the question on how to find the integral submanifold! Gonna think about it and answer you later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the trick: by linearity, the distribution spanned by $V_1$ and $V_2$ is the same as the one spanned by $f(x,y,z)V_1(x,y,z)$ and $g(x,y,z)V_2(x,y,z)$ for $f$ and $g$ non-vanishing functions. It follows that the distribution spanned by $V_1$ and $V_2$ is equal to that spanned by $\{\frac{\partial}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial}{\partial y},\frac{\partial}{\partial y}-\frac{\partial}{\partial z}\}$. Since these two latter vector fields commute, it is easy to find the integral submanifold passing through the point $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$: it is parametrized by $(s,t) \mapsto \varphi_t\circ \psi_s (x_0,y_0,z_0)$, where $\varphi$ and $\psi$ are the respective flows.